# Where can I find images of different versions of cnosdb?

Tags: docker, cnosdb

The code of the cnosdb warehouse is updated very quickly, and there are some compatibility issues between versions, so rollbacks are often needed. But there is only one large version and the latest image in dockerhub. Where can I find those small version images in this area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the official launch of different versions of images at different times. You can log in to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/cnosdb/cnosdb/tags) to check the version at a specific time and roll back.

Answer (score 1):

CnosDB push docker image to docker hub

CnosDb server ： https://hub.docker.com/r/cnosdb/cnosdb/tags

CnosDb meta： https://hub.docker.com/r/cnosdb/cnosdb-meta/tags